# Talend- get results from tdb2Row component and insert into another table

Tags: db2, talend

I'm running a select count query in a tDB2Row component. I need to get the value found and insert it into another table.

I've tried using the propagate query's recordset, but it doesn't make sense to me.

Also what component would i use next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a screenshot of your job as well as the source code out of `tDB2Row`, as it is unclear now how your job looks like. Alternatively, just try adding a schema in the component and adding a row to a `tLogRow`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use tDB2Input component for select query and give schema to it and add tLogRow to it to see the result.
tDB2Row is for dml query like update and delete.

Hope this helps...

Comment: tDB2Input is definitely the component i needed. But in the end i just called a .sh file to run the select count query and then insert the value into another table